# (mac) Need to automatically backup entire FTP server and create an archive

Tags: ftp, mac-osx, wget

Is there a way to grab all files from an FTP server using wget (or similar), then create a zip or tar of the downloaded files? I would like to do this with one command or using Automator, and to happen regularly on a schedule.

I already have `wget -r ftp://(the ip)/* --ftp-user=(my user) --ftp-password=(my pass)` but I don't think wget can compress the files after downloading them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because serverfault.com is not a script writing service.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write me a script, the question was asking if there is a way to automate backups.

Comment: Yes, check out cron.

Comment: If you already have a way to download the files, surely all you need is to use tar (or zip) to compress and archive your files, and then to do some cleanup - is there a reason you need for this to be done in a single command?